# How to remove the the http header option in AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlsession

If invoke the download function, set the "**Authorization**" in the Http Header, and invoke the second function "**downloadTaskWithRequest**", but the http header also include the "**Authorization**" option, from the code,I didn't set the option,How Can I remove the "**Authorization**" option before the  second function invoked, thanks!

```
- (void)download:(NSString *)api source:(NSString *)fileName thumb:(NSInteger)thumb success:(void (^)(UIImage *img))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *redirect = nil;

    NSUserDefaults *info = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *token = [info stringForKey:@"TOKEN"];
    NSString *tokenStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@", token];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Accept": @"application/json",
                                            @"Content-type": @"application/json",
                                            @"Authorization": tokenStr
                                            };
    configuration.discretionary = YES;

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSString *filePath = nil;

    if (0 == thumb) {
        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@?filename=%@",SERVER_ADDR, api, fileName];
    }
    else{
        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@?filename=%@&thumb=%ld",SERVER_ADDR, api,fileName,(long)thumb];
    }


    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    redirect = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error){



                                  NSURLSessionConfiguration *downloadConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
                                  downloadConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
                                  AFURLSessionManager *download = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:downloadConfig];

                                  //download.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

                                  NSURL *realUrl = [response valueForKey:@"URL"];
                                  NSMutableURLRequest *fileRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:realUrl];


                                  NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [download downloadTaskWithRequest:fileRequest
                                                                                                    progress:nil
                                                                                                 destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
                                                                                                     NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
                                                                                                     return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
                                                                                                 }
                                                                                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
                                                                                               if (error) {
                                                                                                   NSLog(@"File downloaded error = %@",error);
                                                                                                   if (failure) {
                                                                                                       failure(error);
                                                                                                   }
                                                                                               }
                                                                                               else{
                                                                                                   NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
                                                                                                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath]];
                                                                                                   if (success) {
                                                                                                       success(image);
                                                                                                   }
                                                                                               }
                                                                                           }];
                                  [downloadTask resume];


                          }];
    [redirect resume];
}
```

Comment: It appears ephemeralSessionConfiguration is reused. Apple docs say "When your app invalidates the session, all ephemeral session data is purged automatically." This suggests to me you need to invalidate your first session prior to setting up the second. Or you could try setting downloadConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = nil

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but, if you're wondering why your `downloadConfig` has an `Authorization` header, then you can try to remove it by replacing the `HTTPAdditionalHeaders` property just like you did with `configuration` (whether by getting the current headers and removing the `Authorization` field, or setting all the headers to `nil`).